# Deserializing xml with XMLScanner causing the output string to be bigger

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, stax, woodstox

Our product upgrade process includes old schema DB export to files (JAXB serialization) then import to the new schema (StAX + JAXB). Sometimes the upgrade fails due to insert errors that caused by values that exceeds their maximum size dispite that they were previously exported from same DB table.

This happened when deserializing xml (In this case with Jaxb but its not related just to Jaxb) and one of the attributes have value with sequence of high surrogate UTF-8 characters the SAX parser have bug causing the output string to be bigger:

3 chars -> (1+2+3=) 6 chars.
6 chars -> (1+2+3+4+5+6=) 21 chars.
(Arithmetic progression of the source chars)

The code is from java 1.7_45 code class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner lines: 976 - 981:

```
else if (c != -1 && XMLChar.isHighSurrogate(c)) {
    if (scanSurrogates(fStringBuffer3)) {
        stringBuffer.append(fStringBuffer3);
    if (entityDepth == fEntityDepth && fNeedNonNormalizedValue){
        fStringBuffer2.append(fStringBuffer3); 
    }
```

**fStringBuffer3** buffer is not cleared between the loops.

Similar code exist (same method name) in com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XML11DocumentScannerImpl lines: 369 - 375. But this time the buffer cleared during the loops:

```
else if (c != -1 && XMLChar.isHighSurrogate(c)) {
        fStringBuffer3.clear();
        if (scanSurrogates(fStringBuffer3)) {
            fStringBuffer.append(fStringBuffer3);
        if (entityDepth == fEntityDepth) {
            fStringBuffer2.append(fStringBuffer3);
        }
   }
```

I checked the java bug database, this bug is not mentioned there.
So I am looking for a fix for this issue, replacing JAXB parser with Woodstox parser solves the bug, 
unfortunately it's too risky for us right now.

The general pattern of my code is (part of method that returns an Object that was deserialized from file):

```
XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(file)); 
try {
    while(xmlStreamReader.hasNext()){
        boolean skipNext = xmlStreamReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT;
        xmlStreamReader.next();
        // If its any other element we are unmarshalling it with JAXB
        if((xmlStreamReader.getEventType()== XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) && !skipNext){
            nextElement = innerDeserializer.deserialize();
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e) {}
```

Have sombody encoutered with this issue? There is any way to make my code use the second piece of code without using XML version 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

If the bug is in the SAX parser which by default the JAXB reference implementation uses for XML processing.  You could create a StAX `XMLStreamReader` on the input and have JAXB unmarshal that.

Comment: This is what we are doing, reading large documents chunks with StAX, while each START_ELEMENT event parsed with JAXB.

Comment: @MaximKirilov - I'm confused where the SAX parser comes in then.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I edited my code above and added a general pattern of my code that shows the combination of StAX with JAXB.

Comment: @MaximKirilov - So the StAX approach works you just consider it to risky, why do you consider it risky?  In addition to Woodstox there is a StAX parser in the JDK/JRE does that work for you?